# OnReceive wont work for alarm android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want the user to be notified when the alarm fires. But it wont notify. I dont know why. I tried other sources it didn't helped at all.

This is my code:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ViewTasksActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //assigned a unique id to notifications
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Testing Notifications")
                .setContentText("")
                .setSubText("Complete the tasks under this activity.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gsoicon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent3)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(m, mNotification);


    }
```

I already put this on the manifest file:

```
 <receiver android:name='com.goalsettingorganizer.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver'>
        </receiver>
```

Setting the alarms code:

```
public void SetAlarms(Context context, int goal_id)
    {
        dbhandler = new MyDBAdapter(context);

        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        List<Activities> allActs = dbhandler.getAllActivitiesByGoal(goal_id);

        for (final Activities act : allActs) {

            //for alarm
            //Create an offset from the current time in which the alarm will go off.

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(act.getEDay()));  //1-31
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(act.getEMonth()) - 1);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(act.getEYear()));//year...

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, act.getHour());
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, act.getMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, act.getSecond());
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, act.getMillisecond());

            //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent3.putExtra("goalid", Integer.toString(goal_id));
            intent3.putExtra("activityId", Integer.toString(act.getActId()));
            intent3.putExtra("activityName", act.getActivityName());
            intent3.putExtra("show", "true");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    act.getActId(), intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            else
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

My error:

I have put getActivity() in PendingIntent rather than getBroadcast(). That's the reason the OnReceive doesn't work.

Comment: you know that there is no need for WakeLock inside onReceive?

Comment: yeah i know. its not used anyway. please ignore that.

Comment: can u help me why it wont display the notification?

Comment: does it hit onReceive method at all ? maybe the problem is with code where you setup an alarm ... this question is really bad ... there is no way to guess why ...

Comment: not really on setting up the an alarm. I tried putting a Toast that displays "true" and it wont show. I will add the setalarm code.

Comment: did you set the permission in your manifest?  add this permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>`

Comment: please see the code. :) thanks

Comment: Karan Mer, i'll try. wait a sec.

Comment: also set your receiver as below `<receiver android:name="com.goalsettingorganizer.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" android:process=":remote" />`

Comment: Karan Mer, below, Susan Mak A said not to put this code -> android:process=":remote"

Comment: Karan Mar, i still dont see the notifications. :( i already added the code u told me.